# How do I stop a currently running cron job executing wget?

Tags: linux, wget, cron, centos-6, plesk

I added a cron job to prime the cache of my website. The command is:

`cd crawler && wget --recursive  --no-parent --domains=example.com --level=inf --reject css,js,png,jpg,mp4,psd,pdf --delete-after  --header "Cookie: has_js=1" -U "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36" https://example.com`

The website has about 20k pages. However my cache is now at 40k pages and still going after 48hrs.   So I want to stop that command running.

To do so I ran:

`ps fauxww | grep -A 1 '[C]RON'`

That gave me

```
root      8174  0.0  0.0 184304  2748 ?        S    Sep28   0:16  \_ CROND
10037     8182  0.0  0.0 106112  1044 ?        Ss   Sep28   0:00  |   \_ /bin/sh -c cd crawler && wget --recursive --no-parent --domains=example.com --level=inf --reject css,js,png,jpg,mp4,psd,pdf --delete-after  --header "Cookie: has_js=1" -U "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36" https://example.com
--
root     23177  0.0  0.0 184300  3556 ?        S    13:00   0:00  \_ CROND
root     23180  0.0  0.2 345556 27648 ?        Ss   13:00   0:00  |   \_ /usr/bin/sw-engine -c /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/php.ini -dauto_prepend_file=sdk.php /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/plesk-mobile/scripts/push_worker.php
root     24754  0.0  0.0 184300  3556 ?        S    13:01   0:00  \_ CROND
root     24755  0.0  0.0 106112  1276 ?        Ss   13:01   0:00      \_ /bin/bash /usr/bin/run-parts /etc/cron.hourly
```

I could see the process id of 8182 so I then ran

`kill 8182`

Now when I run
`ps fauxww | grep -A 1 '[C]RON'`

I get this

```
10037     8182  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Zs   Sep28   0:00  |   \_ [sh] <defunct>
root      7120  0.0  0.0 184300  3556 ?        S    13:10   0:00  \_ CROND
guy       7123  0.0  0.0 106112  1164 ?        Ss   13:10   0:00  |   \_ /bin/sh -c /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/fetch_url 'https://example.com/cron.php' > /dev/null
guy       7127  0.0  0.0 106112  1212 ?        S    13:10   0:00  |       \_ /bin/bash /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/fetch_url https://example.com/cron.php
--
root     21941  0.0  0.0 184300  3556 ?        S    13:20   0:00  \_ CROND
root     21947  0.1  0.2 345556 27644 ?        Ss   13:20   0:00      \_ /usr/bin/sw-engine -c /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/php.ini -dauto_prepend_file=sdk.php /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/plesk-mobile/scripts/push_worker.php
root      2737  0.0  0.0  21104   308 ?        Ss    2018   0:00 /usr/sbin/atd
```

Critically the wget command is still running. As in the directory with the cache files is is growing by the second.

So how do I stop that wget command in its tracks before my server runs out of space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you killed `/bin/sh` which was the parent of `wget` you were after. You *did not* do anything to `wget`.

To kill `wget` with `kill` you need to find the PID of `wget`. `ps fauxww | grep -A 2 '[C]RON'` (or more than `2`) could have shown you the right `wget`. Now it may be too late to find `wget` this way because as an [orphaned process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_process) it was adopted by another process which [may](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/250153/108618) or may not match `[C]RON`.

Find the PID of `wget` with `pidof wget` or `ps … | grep [w]get`, not relying on its relation to `CROND` because the relation may be no more. In case of many `wget` processes you may need to investigate further to find the right PID among many. Then `kill` it.

Expect success, unless you target the wrong process again. Your previous attempt did not kill `wget` because you did not target `wget` at all.

Comment: Legend. That did it. Do I need to do anything to undo killing the incorrect process?

Comment: @gMaximus No, I think there is no need. The shell you had killed was going to die after `wget` exits anyway. It may be you misled cron into thinking the job ended early, but now it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Thank you. You're a life saver.